# Vite: img src alias not working when passing as component props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have configured Vite with an alias `"@"` as `"./src"`.

Using the alias directly as `<img>.src` is ok:

```html
<!-- this is ok -->
<img src="@/assets/icon-1.svg">
```

but passing the `src` as a prop is not working:

```html
<!-- ComponentA -->
<template>
  <img :src="imgSrc">
</template>

<!-- Parent Component: alias not resolved as expected; imgSrcWithAlias is "@/assets/icon-1.svg"  -->
<component-a :img-src="imgSrcWithAlias" />
```

Is there any solution to use file path alias when passing props?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asset URLs must be manually resolved in script with the `import` keyword:

```html
<script setup>
import imgSrcWithAlias from '@/assets/icon-1.svg'
</script>

<template>
  <component-a :img-src="imgSrcWithAlias" />
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-img-urls?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: Thanks! I also had to add the `resolve` config from your StackBlitz demo to my `nuxt.config.js` to get it working.

Comment: this will mark all images as `prefetch` to read them on page load.
don't do this if you are using responsive images for various resolutions. Then they will be all loaded at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

@tony19 Answer was what works for me. Using Vue 3 with Vite + TypeScript (Js should work too!) The only difference, is that if aren't using a script with the "setup" attribute: **You need to import the image, and return it inside the export default**. See:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
//Import the images:
import feedImg from './assets/img/feed.png'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    //Return the imgs:
    return {
      feedImg
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

After that, you just need to bind the image to the prop on the component usage:

```html
<ImageComponent
   :imgSrc="feedImg"
   alt="Videos on homepage"
 />
```

And load it on the component itself, binding the src on the img tag:

```js
<template>
  <img :alt="alt" :src="imgSrc" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    imgSrc: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    alt: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
})
</script>
```